# Algebraic structure $(Q,\cdot)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a two question, about this task:

The task is: Examine the algebraic structure $(Q,\cdot)$.

Why algebraic structure $(Q,\cdot)$ is not a group ?
The inverse element is $\frac{1}{x}$.

If not a group, is this structure a commutative monoid?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Because there is no $x\in\Bbb Q$ such that $0\cdot x=1$.

Comment: Though technically, if it hasn't been established that $1$ is the unit yet, I should say that it's because there is no $x\in\Bbb Q$ such that, for all $y\in \Bbb Q$, $y\cdot(0\cdot x)=y=(0\cdot x)\cdot y$.

Comment: $(\mathbb{Q}^*,\cdot)$ is a group (where $\mathbb{Q}^*=\mathbb{Q}-\{0\}$)

Comment: If not a group, is this structure a commutative monoid?

Comment: Well, Srdjan, do you know what a commutative monoid is?

Comment: Earth to Srdjan; come in, please.